# awk desired data data from file and print column wise

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a text file like below.

```
mark     10 20 30
lawrence 40 22 60
mark     11 12 13
mike     15 16 17
lawrence 21 22 23
mike     31 32 33
mike     41 42 47
```

I want to process it and produce output to conform to these conditions:

- One line for each unique name (first column). 
  So, for the above example, there should be three output lines;
  one each for "mark", "lawrence" and "mike".
- Output looks superficially like the input:

  - Four columns.
  - First column of the output is name (first column of the input).
  - Second, third and fourth columns are integers.
- The second column
  is the number of occurrences of the name in the first column.
- The third column
  is the number of occurrences of the name in the first column
  with a value of 20 in the third column of the input.
- The fourth column
  is the number of occurrences of the name in the first column
  with a value of 22 in the third column of the input.

Expected output:

```
mark     2  1  0
mike     3  0  0
lawrence 2  0  2
```

I've written

```
... | awk '{ c[$1]++ } END { for (name in c) print name, c[name] }'
```

My code only outputs

```
mark     2 
mike     3 
lawrence 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
    {name[$1]++}      #Counts how many times each name appear
    $3==20{x20[$1]++} #Counts how many times 20 appears in third column
    $3==22{x22[$1]++} #Counts how many times 22 appears in third column
    END{
        for (i in name){
            printf "%s %d %d %d\n",i,name[i],x20[i],x22[i]
        }
    }
' file
```

Output:

```
mike 3 0 0
lawrence 2 0 2
mark 2 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar concept to [@Quasimodo's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/585539/133219) but using the values `20` and `22` in one place rather than 3 and without hard-coding the values into the names of arrays:

```
awk '
    { namesCnt[$1]++; pairsCnt[$1,$3]++ }
    END {
        for (name in namesCnt) {
            print name, namesCnt[name], pairsCnt[name,20]+0, pairsCnt[name,22]+0
        }
    }
' file
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the output lined up into columns, as shown in the question,
take either of the other answers ([Quasímodo’s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/585535/80216#585539) or [Ed Morton’s](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/585535/80216#585547))
and pipe it into `column -t`.